# How to get response in string format after call URL in browser in php

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have used below php code to insert the data into table...but i need response 1 after successfully insert and 0 for failed insert...or any msg like 'your msg has been successfully inserted'..

```
<?php

$myname=$_GET["name"];
$mycity=$_GET["city"];
$myname=urlencode($myname);
$mycity=urlencode($mycity);
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$sql="insert into tbl_sazal(name,city) values ('$myname','$mycity') ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "1";
}
else{
echo "0";
}
?>
```

also for reference i m calling below url

```
http://localhost/testurl/test1.php?name=akash&city=ngong
```

Thanks....

Comment: confused - your already doing that `if($result){` ...

Comment: thanks u @Dagon...but i always getting 1 for failed and success..if i use wrong variable in the browser then blank row created in table...i want i any thing wrong no data will insert...how i will set condition...thanks again

Comment: blank row is still  a successful insert. you want `empty()` or `isset()` to check if the parsed variables are there

Comment: thanks @Dagon ..if anyone type wrong variable in the url ...suppose there is name..he wrong type nname..then what i will do...

Comment: what is wrong vs right name? how do you know what names are valid?

Comment: this is my url http://localhost/testurl/test1.php?name=akash&city=ngong ... here name if anyone use nname which main variable for this url....i dono mentioning value as akash...thanks

Comment: what does echo $result; return?

Comment: @ehwas ...but i always getting 1 for failed and success..if i use wrong variable in the browser then blank row created in table...i want i any thing wrong no data will insert..

Comment: What do you mean by wrong variable?
You don\'t compare input to anything.

Comment: still not sure what you want name to be or not to be ,b ut to check its not blank you can use `if(empty($_GET['name'])){..empty name}`

Comment: @Dagon thanks u...i have already use it and get my result...but blank data insert into db...how i will stop it..thanks again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not passing link identifier to mysql_query();
It returns error as string which in boolean except if the string is 0, it is true;

Change your code on line 10 to

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

Comment: ..thank u...i have use it..